# Strange javascript syntax error reported by console

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I use php to generate a table of thumbnail images and captions. A simple javascript controls the display of these thumbnails and their captions in the main image area.

The last image in the second row (3-08.jpg) gives the error "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list."

The strange thing is that the ) is there, the same as all the others. And, as this list is automatically generated, there isn't any difference in the code for each thumbnail & caption.

Here is the script:

```
function changeImage(filename, imagetitle)
{
   document.getElementById('mainImage').src = filename;
   document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = imagetitle;
}
```

and here is the generated html:

```
                        <tr align="center" valign="bottom" class="thumbnails">
                      <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-01.jpg','Attractive Tamarac Trail home with comfortable living spaces and a beautifully landscaped yard.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-01.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-02.jpg','The tiled entry is a great spot to shed those boots and coats - and a pretty spot to relax, too.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-02.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-03.jpg','Beautiful maple flooring and exquisite detailing add a lot of character to this home.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-03.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-04.jpg','Counter seating will allow your family to grab a quick meal while visiting with the cook.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-04.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                            </tr>
                    <tr align="center" valign="bottom" class="thumbnails">
                      <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-05.jpg','Dining is delightful in this area full of windows.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-05.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-06.jpg','The main floor is open and inviting.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-06.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-07.jpg','A cozy and carpeted living room makes a wonderful gathering place for family and friends.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-07.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-08.jpg','The lower level has a very nice family room, two bedrooms, and a full bath.  But, wait... there's more!')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-08.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                            </tr>
                    <tr align="center" valign="bottom" class="thumbnails">
                      <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-09.jpg','Formerly used as a stained glass studio, the artist in your family will enjoy making this large space their own.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-09.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-10.jpg','This spacious wood shop, complete with outside entry, will delight any woodworker.')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-10.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-11.jpg','The deck will be a popular spot during the warmer months. ')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-11.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                  <td>                <a href="javascript:changeImage('adminNew/images/3-12.jpg','We all need a little more storage!')"><img src="adminNew/images/3-12.jpg"> </a>
           </td> 
                                            </tr>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this error is occurring?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why this question has been put on hold: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." This isn't a typo, surely the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

Your description contains a single-quote and is wrapped in single-quotes, so the string ends with "wait... there", followed by the (to JS) nonsense `s more!'`.

Make sure you escape the description strings prior to building the page, or you'll run into quite a few issues like this. You need to (at the very least) escape all quotes, both single and double, by preceding them with a backslash (`\'`). You should also escape backslashes in the same fashion.

PHP appears to provide a function for this: [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Bear in mind that, if these descriptions are taken from user input, you need to be very careful to sanitize and escape anything that could allow them to script the browser, or you'll be vulnerable to all kinds of XSS.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out, also, and was about to update my question when I saw your response.

My solution was str_replace to change the single quotes to a right single quote (&rsquo;).